# MOSFET overheats and results in short circuit

Tags: mosfet, diodes, solenoid

I use this 40V, N-Channel NexFET Power MOSFET
http://www.ti.com/product/CSD18504Q5A

in

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb2EBu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The solenoid takes 25A peak current. (Rated drain current is 50A)

In this setup, MOSFET overheats and shorts after some time.
What is wrong with this setup? Please advise.

P.S. I am a noob.

Comment: Actual drive voltage on the MOSFET? Also PCB layout or photo of your arrangement.

Comment: 5V to Gate is applied

Comment: What kind of monster solenoid dissipates 300 W?

Comment: @jms This is used to actuate a gear switching assembly. The ON pulse lasts for about 350ms.

Comment: Link to the heatsink data would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a 4.5V gate drive this MOSFET has a maximum Rds(on) of about 10m\$\Omega\$ at 25°C, perhaps as much as 15m\$\Omega\$ at a safe higher junction temperature. If we use that value, power dissipation can be in the 10W range. See the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd18504q5a.pdf).

That's rather high for such a tiny package and may be virtually impossible to achieve with a reasonable setup. At the reference 50°C/W (see below note as to specifics- that's 1 square inch of 2 ounce copper- not insignificant) it obviously will burn out rather quickly (500°C rise is not going to be possible). At 125°C/W (second layout below) it will probably fry in seconds.

You need a MOSFET with much lower Rds(on) and/or a MOSFET that is in a package capable of dissipating more power.

Note that if you're feeling fooled by the datasheet- that is an 'absolute maximum' rating- not something you should be designing to. Constraints often turn out to be other than the first number you run across- in this case it's thermal. **All** constraints must be simultaneously respected or you may have a bad day.

> (2) Device mounted on FR4 material with 1-inch2 (6.45-cm2), 2-oz. (0.071-mm thick) Cu.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. I will wait for more opinion before marking yours as answer.

Comment: This MOSFET was a TO-220, attached with a heatsink (the one that you bolt to the hole on TO-220). Are there any packages that could dissipate more power than this setup?

Comment: That does not match the MOSFET in the datasheet you linked and I have idea what a 'TO-22' is. Of course if you have a totally different part than in the question the specifics will vary- just use the methods I outlined and do the calculations. You can get parts that will dissipate 1000W comfortably.

Comment: Sorry, that was a TO-220. The same MOSFET is given in different packages by TI.

Comment: A part in a TO-220 package should be able to dissipate 10W okay, but read the datasheet. The heatsink required will be fairly large or will require a fan.

Comment: @KarthikNishanth - And the fact that it takes a while to overheat is an excellent indicator that whatever heatsink you're using is marginal.